Can Pikmin flower in the Rescue Command Post?
Typically, when you leave Pikmin sprouts unplucked for a while they will flower over time. However, there's no timer in the Rescue Command Post you return to between days.
Will Pikmin sprouts flower if left unplucked in the Rescue Command Post?

Yes, Pikmin can flower in the Rescue Command Post if left unplucked for long enough. Tested by leaving them unplucked for around 10 minutes and came back to see them flowered.

